# How to generate xml tag with dot (.) using xsd schema in vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

i am going to generate xml for ledger in tally software. For that i create a xsd file.. In tally ledger xml,
some tags are generated with dot. for example

i follow the below coding :

```
<xs:complexType name="Ledger1">
   <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"  name="BLOOD.GROUPS"
   type="BLOODGROUPS"/>

   <xs:complexType name="BLOODGROUPS">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="BLOODGROUPS"  type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="BLOODGROUPS"  type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="BLOODGROUPS"  type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

the result generated using above xsd is as below

```
<BLOODGROUPS>
  <BLOOD>A+</BLOOD>
  <BLOOD>B+</BLOOD>
  <BLOOD>O-</BLOOD>
</BLOODGROUPS>
```

but expected result is :

```
<BLOOD.GROUPS>
  <BLOOD>A+</BLOOD>
  <BLOOD>B+</BLOOD>
  <BLOOD>O-</BLOOD>
</BLOOD.GROUPS>
```

can anyone help me how to declare xsd for the above expected result
in vb.net .i am using version 3.5

Comment: Your example outputs look a little... confused. You have `<BLOOD>` opening tags and `</ADDRESS>` closing tags - which makes me suspicious that these aren't genuinely output that you've copied from somewhere but something that you've free-typed.

Comment: Now Check it. Sorry for that @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatily you cannot set the `TableName` with `.` character directly. But, you can fill dataset using `DataAdapter` then write that dataset into xml file using `DataSet1.WriteXml("D:\\fileName.xml")` method. I have created a sample file using that method.

```
Dim Da As new SqlDataAdapter("Select Query", Connection)
Dim Ds As new DataSet()
Da.Fill(Ds, "Table.Name");
Ds.WriteXml("D:\\tempFile.xml")
```

**Sample file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table.Name>
    <CompanyID>1</CompanyID>
    <IndustryID>98</IndustryID>
    <AwardID>MA000012</AwardID>
    <AgreementID>9</AgreementID>
    <CreateUser>1</CreateUser>
    <CreateDate>2014-05-03T14:31:00+05:30</CreateDate>
  </Table.Name>
</NewDataSet>
```